# What is the meaning of "php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed"?

Tags: php, libmemcache

**What is the meaning of "php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed"?**

when i'm using memcache, i found this "What is the meaning of "php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed"?" appears when running the methods of memcache.

Answer (score 0):

That usually means your `DNS resolution` is not working correctly. PHP cannot get the ip-address for hostnames used in the Memcache functions.

**Your options**

- Check/fix that DNS-lookups can be done correctly.
- Change your code to `use ip-addresses` instead of hostnames

**Example**

```
Memcache::connect("1.2.3.4");           // replace with correct ip
Memcache::getServerStatus("1.2.3.4");   // --- '' ---
// etc other functions using hostname
```